# How do you install the Net::SFTP module on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, sftp

I'm new to Perl. How do you install the Net::SFTP module? I'm running Ubuntu Linux. I believe there's a simple way to do it from the command line, like by calling $ cpan install or something.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the command-line way to install perl modules is:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::SFTP"
```

There are instances where it is better to install perl modules from the packages or ports or other similar systems which come with a particular distribution. Because some Perl modules make use of compiled C code, and C code compilation and dependencies can vary. For instance, I use OpenBSD for most of my servers and I generally use the version I find in the packages for a given version of the OS if there is one, and if there isn't one in the packages I assume it is safe to install it from CPAN and that generally works for me.

Answer (score 4):

An option that's quite common is to use the packages from your distribution, with `apt-get` or `aptitude` *(or any graphical tool you like)*.

If that package is not provided by your distribution, you can :

- First, install the `cpan` command, if not already installed, with something like : `apt-get install cpan`
- And, then, use the `cpan` command to install your package : `cpan -i Net:SFTP`

  *(Note it'll ask lots of questions -- like should it also install required packages)*
- If needed, you can access the documentation of the `cpan` command : `cpan -h` or `perldoc -F /usr/bin/cpan` *(might require the `perl-doc` package)*

Answer (score 2):

Net::SFTP used to be included in Debian/Ubuntu repositories but at some point it was removed because it requires the pari library that has a license not acceptable for Debian.

An alternative is to use Net::SFTP::Foreign available as libnet-sftp-foreign-perl (or also installable from CPAN).